# How to get value from next iteration of foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to print out entries from a SQL database. Some of the entries are images, and I want to parse those and put them in appropriate HTML markup.

**Database Example**

```
id | datatype  | typetext

78 | paragraph | "hello"
79 | image     | "image.jpg"
80 | paragraph | "goodbye"
```

The column `datatype` signifies what type of data is being stored in a given row, and I want to catch when the value of `datatype` is "image" - then jump to the following `typetext` column and prepare the appropriate markup for this image.

For instance, some psuedo-code of what I'm trying to do:

```
if(column is datatype){
    if(datatype == 'image'){
        echo '<p>' . data inside accompanying typetext column . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Here's my current code:

```
//the array of the blog entry
foreach($entry as $key => $entryUnit){

    //the array of the entry unit
    foreach($entryUnit as $column => $cell){

        if($column == 'datatype'){
            if($key == 'image'){
                echo '<br/>';
                echo '<p style="color: pink;">' $cell . $entryUnit[$column + 1] . '</p>';
                echo '<br/>';
            }
        }

        else if($column == 'typetext'){
            echo '<br/>';
            echo $cell;
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

In the first `if` statement, I try jumping to the next column with `echo '<p style="color: pink;">' $cell . $entryUnit[$column + 1] . '</p>';`, but this doesn't work.

I've also tried utilizing the `next()` function, like:

```
echo '<p>' . next($cell) . '</p>';`
```

..but this also doesn't work as I thought it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need *that* nested `foreach` loops, you can everything in just one simple `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($entry as $entryUnit){
    if($entryUnit['datatype'] == "image"){
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<p style="color: pink;">' . $entryUnit['typetext'] . '</p>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }elseif($entryUnit['datatype'] == "paragraph"){
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $entryUnit['typetext'];
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the clarification and the help.

Answer (score 2):

Somethink like this should work:

```
 //the array of the blog entry
foreach($entry as $key => $entryUnit){
$i=0;
    //the array of the entry unit
    foreach($entryUnit as $column => $cell){

        if($column == 'datatype'){
            if($key == 'image'){
$i++;
                echo '<br/>';
                echo '<p style="color: pink;">' $cell . $entryUnit[$i] . '</p>';
                echo '<br/>';
            }
        }

        else if($column == 'typetext'){
            echo '<br/>';
            echo $cell;
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if reset $i inside the first loop or outside both loops, and check if increment only if $key == 'image' or increment in the other case also.